# Upgrading GhostScript 9.02 to 9.05

Tags: macos, ghostscript

Actually i wanted to update my existing Ghostscript from version 9.02 to 9.05 latest build. When i run make inside the 9.05 package, i get the following Error:

```
if [ x != x ]; then LD_RUN_PATH=; export LD_RUN_PATH; fi; \     XCFLAGS= XINCLUDE= XLDFLAGS= XLIBDIRS= XLIBS= \     FEATURE_DEVS= DEVICE_DEVS= DEVICE_DEVS1= DEVICE_DEVS2= DEVICE_DEVS3= \  DEVICE_DEVS4= DEVICE_DEVS5= DEVICE_DEVS6= DEVICE_DEVS7= DEVICE_DEVS8= \     DEVICE_DEVS9= DEVICE_DEVS10= DEVICE_DEVS11= DEVICE_DEVS12= \    DEVICE_DEVS13= DEVICE_DEVS14= DEVICE_DEVS15= DEVICE_DEVS16= \   DEVICE_DEVS17= DEVICE_DEVS18= DEVICE_DEVS19= DEVICE_DEVS20= \   DEVICE_DEVS_EXTRA= \    /bin/sh <./obj/ldt.tr Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_iconv_open", referenced from:
      _opvp_to_utf8 in gdevopvp.o   "_iconv", referenced from:
      _opvp_to_utf8 in gdevopvp.o   "_iconv_close", referenced from:
      _opvp_to_utf8 in gdevopvp.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make: *** [bin/gs] Error 1
```

I am using Mac OS Lion X as my development machine.

May i know how do i overcome this ?  your help is pretty much appreciated.Thanks..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have two possible solutions. First, look at the "NOTE:" section in this link:
http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Make.htm#MacOSX

Second, try doing:

```
./configure --with-libiconv=no
```

This will disable the OpenPrinting Vector (opvp) device, but since that is long deprecated, I doubt you need to use it.